# Laravel: Route [PackageController.fetch] not defined

Tags: mysql, ajax, laravel

This is blade file.I am pulling data from database and making dynamically dependent on first dropdown box.

```
<div class="container">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"  href="css/mystyle.css">


    <div class="row justify-content-center">
        <div class="col-md-8">
            <div class="card">
                <div class="card-header">Welcome {{ Auth::user()->name }}</div>


                        </thead>
                        <tbody>
                          <tr>
                            <td>

                               <select class="form-control input-lg dynamic" name="service_type[]" id="service_type[]" data-parsley-required="true" data-dependent="service_name[]">
                                <option value="">Select Service Type</option>
                                @foreach ($services as $service )
                                <option value="{{ $service->service_type }}">{{ $service->service_type }}</option>
                                @endforeach
                              </select>                         

                            </td>


                              </select></td>
                            <td><input type="text" name="service_price[]" class="form-control input-lg dynamic"></td>
                            <td><a href="#" class="btn btn-danger remove">-</td>
                          </tr>
                        </tbody>

                      </table>

                    </div>
                  </div>

                </div>     
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    {{ csrf_field() }}
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function(){
    $('.dynamic').change(function(){
        if($(this).val() != '')
        {
          var select = $(this).attr("id");
          var value = $(this).val();
          var dependent = $(this).data('dependent');
          var _token = $('input[name="_token"]').val();
          $.ajax({
            url:"{{ route('PackageController.fetch') }}",method:"POST",data:{select:select,value:value,_token:_token,dependent:dependent},
            success:function(result)
            {
              $('#'+dependent).html(result);
            }
          })
        }


    });

  });


</script>
```

I have a controller with function fetch

**PackageController.php**

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Http\Requests;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use App\Package;
use App\Service;
use DB;
use Session;

class PackageController extends Controller
{
    public function index()
    {}
    function fetch(Request $request)
    {
        $select = $request->get('select');
        $value = $request->get('value');
        $dependent = $request->get('dependent');
        $data = DB::table('services')
                ->where($select,$value)
                ->groupBy($dependent)
                ->get();
        $output = '<option value="">Select '.ucfirst($dependent).'</option>';
        foreach ($$data as $row) {
            $output .= '<option value="'.$row->$dependent.'">'.$row->$dependent.'</option>';
            # code...
        }
        echo $output;
    }
}

Route::resource('package','PackageController');
Route::get('package/fetch','PackageController@fetch');
```

But showing this error

> Route [PackageController.fetch] not defined. (View:
>   /home/devadmin/.config/composer/vendor/laravel/installer/serenseprj/resources/views/package.blade.php

Comment: post your blade file how you are calling the route

Comment: @chaitra your route is pointing some different location. Try to change your controller file and controller and then check. Change name to `PackagesController` instead of `PackageController`. I think it may help

Comment: I posted my blade file

Comment: @chaitra see my answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

since you posted your blade file you are calling `url` using `named route` which you have not defined in your `web.php`

Change your route to

```
Route::get('package/fetch','PackageController@fetch')->name('PackageController.fetch');
```

and in your js part you are calling `GET` route as `POST` either change your route to `POST` in `web.php` or in your js change it to `GET`
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It appears you have forgotten the public keyword from your function declaration:

```
public function fetch(Request $request)
{
    $select = $request->get('select');
    $value = $request->get('value');
    $dependent = $request->get('dependent');
    $data = DB::table('services')
        ->where($select,$value)
        ->groupBy($dependent)
        ->get();
    $output = '<option value="">Select '.ucfirst($dependent).'</option>';
    foreach ($$data as $row) {
        $output .= '<option value="'.$row->$dependent.'">'.$row->$dependent.'</option>';
        # code...
    }
    echo $output;
}
```